# Render Canvas in an System.Controls.Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Canvas` that i fill over an `ObservableCollection<UIElement>` with paths. I also use this to draw thumbnails in my `ListView` what kills my performance on lower hardware.

I know when my `ObservableCollection` is changing so i want to just render it as `System.Controls.Image`. (Other ideas are welcome)

But I find nothing -  there is a lot forms stuff or saving it as file. But I just want it at runtime.

**How can I render my `Canvas` as `System.Controls.Image` ?**

On Ashs suggestion i tried to render it inside a visual brush - what doesn't render anything - even if i try to bind the datacontext from the parent.

```
                            <Rectangle Width="100"
                                       Height="100">
                                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>

                                    <VisualBrush>
                                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                            <custom:CustomPreviewSvgControl PreviewViewModel="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Rectangle}}}"
                                                                            Width="100"
                                                                            Height="100"
                                            />
                                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    </VisualBrush>
                                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            </Rectangle>
```

Comment: use VisualBrush, maybe?

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: An ObservableCollection of UIElements is the wrong approach. Use an ItemsControl instead, and bind it to a collection of data items. Then use DataTemplate(s) to visualize the items. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: U mean taking a `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel` ? Because I need a canvas anyway to get my svg paths on the right position?